# Working with a \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} and need to insert table

Tags: tables, two-column, ieeetran, journal

I need some help here please.

I'm working in a `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}` document. So i have two columns. I need to insert a table, this table contains 3 columns and like 11 rows but the rows contains a lot of information. So i need to insert the table using the two columns space. 
I have something like this

```
information from column 1            information in column 2
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

So when i insert the table go just to one column. like this

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
info & info & info \\
a    & b    & c    \\
d    & e    & f   
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

information from column 1            information in column 2
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
________________________
info     info     info
 a        b         c 
 d        e         f 
________________________
```

But i need something like this

```
information from column 1            information in column 2
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
_____________________________________________________________
info                     info                       info
 a                        b                          c 
 d                        e                          f 
_____________________________________________________________
```

Thanks in advanced, and sorry for bad english

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Would a table spreading over both columns be a solution?

Comment: Yes i think that could work. Let me try that solution

Comment: @CarlosArronteBello To span both columns, use `\begin{table*}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `tabularx`. You can either code for a table within a single column, or a table which spreads over two columns. For that you have the `table*` environment.

However, it places its contents at the `top` of a page, contrary to the `table` environment in one-column documents. The `stfloats` package (from the `sttools` bundle) lets you use in addition the `[b]` specifier, to place the float at the `bottom` of pages.

In the `sttools` bundle, there's also the `cuted` package, which defines a `strip` environment, which spreads over two columns anywhere. This is not a floating environment, so we have to use the `\captionof{table}{...}` command, from the `capt-of` package (the `caption` package defines the same command, but it seems to have problems with the `IEEEtran` class).

Her's a demo of one-column and two-column table:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs, capt-of, tabularx}%
\usepackage{cuted, stfloats}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{my-label}
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}XX@{}}
    information from column 1 & information in column 2 \\
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx \\
  \end{tabularx}\\[6pt]
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
    info & info & info \\
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2-3]
\begin{strip}
  \centering
  \captionof{table}{My caption}
  \label{my-label}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XX@{}}
    information from column 1 & information in column 2 \\
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx \\
  \end{tabularx}\\[6pt]
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
    info & info & info \\
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \mbox{}
\end{strip}
\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below syntax will fulfill your requirement:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
   \begin{tabular*}{20pc}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
   information from column 1 & information in column 2\\
   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
   \end{tabular*}\\[6pt]
   \begin{tabular*}{20pc}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}
   \hline
   info & info & info \\
   a    & b    & c    \\
   d    & e    & f    \\
   \hline
   \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```